# Is there a more concise way to say "cars stuck in traffic"?

Tags: word-request

I am searching a word for describing cars stuck in traffic.  When I googled the phrase "stuck cars", I found out that stuck cars imply cars stuck in ditches rather than traffic.

Comment: My question has been edited.  I would like to know a modifier (adjective) that modifies the noun "cars", such as "stuck cars", or "congested cars"

Comment: Cars also get stuck in snow, probably more often than ditches.

Comment: Yeah, snow or mud.

Comment: @rama9, I don't think there's an adjective for that in English.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly you mean by an abbreviation, but in English, a situation when there are just too many cars on the road where little to no movement is possible is traditionally called [**a traffic jam**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/traffic-jam) or [**a traffic congestion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_congestion). To find out more about what other expressions related to cars stuck in traffic exist in English, follow the link to the Wikipedia article on *traffic congestion* that I provided.

Example:

> The reason I'm so late today is because my car got caught in **a huge traffic jam** this morning.

Comment: It's probably more likely that you would say "...because I got caught in a huge traffic jam..."  Saying your car was caught sounds a bit odd, although it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I was trying to think of an illustrative, yet simple, example that involved a car. I think that's why I ended up with *my car* there instead of *I*.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *bumper-to-bumper traffic*.

> Due to a truck collision, cars on the freeway were stuck in **bumper-to-bumper** traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, "Heavy Traffic", "Congestion", "Clogged Roads", "Heavy Delays", or, even depending on the cause, you could say, "Gaper's Delay" or "Rubbernecking" if the cause is because people are staring at an accident. You could also say, "Traffic was at a standstill", or call the highway "A parking lot".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gridlock](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gridlock) or deadlock. It is defined by Oxford Dictionaries as follows:

> A situation of very severe traffic congestion.
>
> ‘the city reaches gridlock during peak hours’